# ToRecipients Will Not UpdateEWS Managed API 2.2

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600367(v=exchg.150).aspx) 
I am trying to update ToRecipients property is writable.
When I run the following code in Powershell:

```
foreach ( $Item in $SearchResults ) {
            Write-Output $item.Subject
            $Item.Load()
            $Item.Sender.Name = 'TS'
            $item.IsRead = $false
            $item.Subject = 'Test'
            $item.ToRecipients.Name = 'DisplayName Three'
            $Item.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AlwaysOverwrite)             
        }
```

It would Save subject, however neither Sender or ToRecipients get updated.

Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> > According to MSDN I am trying to update ToRecipients property is writable

No that property is ReadOnly according to the documentation eg

[image]

That property is just a cacluated property based on the contents of the Recipients collection which I believe is also ReadOnly on a Message once its been received in EWS.